# Medical Family Tree - Information to Obtain

Tags: research-methods, medicine

For most people I'm not going to have any information on them.

For anyone with medical information, I find that I'm only going to get the cause of death.

But for those people who I can obtain more detailed information on, like my more immediate family, or when obtaining information on more distant relatives that voluntarily share things...

What kind of information should I be obtaining? I can't seem to find anything that helps to determine this online. Everything I seem to find is the same thing as when you go to the hospital and are asked about certain things that occurred to your immediate family.

Would you consider having an appendix removed an important thing to record?

And what else is there? Is there any type of a questionnaire to help with this? Unless the person tells me "I had my gall bladder removed", I'm not going to remember to inquire "do you have a gall bladder? did you or any close relatives have a problem with gall stones?"

And then what kind of accessory information would be pertinent to record? I'm thinking dates of affliction, time of issue, if it resolved itself...

I usually rely off of genealogical programs to help me with this. When I discovered programs that recorded educational/occupational/occupancy records, I was astounded, and they helped me determine questions to ask. But I can't seem to find any genealogical program that helps index this.

Comment: I've certainly used medical records to help with genealogical research before, but I haven't felt the need to record that level of detail.  While that kind of information may help flesh-out a family history, I suspect that what you should record is going to be entirely a matter of personal opinion.

Comment: You might find this [related question](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/9965/methods-to-organize-medical-genealogy-information) interesting regarding software capabilities.

Answer (score -2):

[image: medical history form]
Do a search for "medical history form" and also GENOGRAM